# Server architecture depending on the capacity

Tags: python, websocket, server, capacity

I am new at Server side,
but I have gotten a chance to design and implement a server that will cover around 2000~3000 client.

And I am thinking that I will use `Python` and `Websocket`, though I don't know this choice is appropriate.

In this point, I am curious on how to design the server.
I think there must be some architecture normally in use depending on capacity that server handles.

Otherwise, Could I use a `Websocket` server offered by some python package like `Tornado` or `Django`?

I hope that I can get any information on this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experiences using haproxy in front of [sockjs-tornado](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado). Depending on how complex your server-side logic, routing, and persistence requirements are, you could write all your server endpoints using tornado and use SQLAlchemy to handle writes to a relational database or use a non SQL data store like Redis.

If your main requirement is real-time interactivity it might be worth investigating [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions could be Pyramid, sockjs, gunicorn, and gevent. Nginx probably better suits to be a frontend than Apache, but of course if you do not have any lengthy processing on the backend, any decent asynchronous Python server with websocket and sockjs support (not sure about socket.io as an alternative) will work for you out of the box.

Lenghty processing should be offloaded to some queue workers anyway, so asynchronous server will fit the bill.

Just check whether all used datastore/database adapters are compatible with your server solution be it asynchronous or multi-threading.